# Code works with F8 but doesn't with F5 - vba web scraping

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have the following code which works fine when run with F8 from inside VBA, but when running it with F5 it throws an error...when I check the error I see that **doc variable** is empty. what is the reason and how can i fix it so it runs without any error:

```
    Sub b()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
'Dim con As Object


ie.navigate "https://www.techinasia.com/companies/worq-2"

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = ie.document

j = 0
    Do Until j = 3
    Set con = doc.getElementsByClassName("entity__type")(j)
    Cells(5, 3 + j).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("entity__type")(j).innerText
    j = j + 1
    Loop

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: What error, and where is it thrown?

Comment: Usually this points to a timing issue: your page is not fully loaded when you try to access the document object.  Try putting a Wait in your code before the `Set doc =` line

Comment: I've added this line of code: `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))` before `Set doc =  ` and `set con =  ` and in this case it works. But it is something i don't get it...I have thought that checking `ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE` shall be enough but it seems it isn't..Could you please explain ?

Comment: The page may have been loaded, but there could be asynchronous page process in the back ground.  Another way is to write a wait loop until the element appears (of course put a limit read count).

Comment: How can I check when the element appears ? Can I use smth similar with the way the loading of html page is validated ? e.g. `readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE`